# git gemfury push conflicts

Tags: ruby, git, github

I'm using gemfury and git with Ruby for the first time and am having trouble doing a push to my remote gemfury repository:

`git push fury master`

I get an error message saying that I need to do a git pull to update my code with the latest changes.

After doing a git pull I get several conflict errors but it doesn't make sense as it's a fresh clone of the master repo. Others from my team don't seem to get the same errors when building the same package.

I've tried deleting the local repository and doing a git clone again. I've also tried doing a git reset but without any progress.

Any help or pointers would be helpful as I haven't been able to solve this issue yet and it's starting to fustrate me. Thanks!

Comment: Run `git pull fury --rebase master` before git-push. You could run `git fetch fury master && git cherry HEAD FETCH_HEAD` to check if any new commits have been updated to the remote master.